# Audio being recorded from AVCaptureSession is generating a "Bad Address" error when streaming to another device

Tags: swift, audio, stream, avfoundation, avaudiosession

Thanks so much in advance, I know this question may be hard to follow. If you need any clarification or want me to explain a method better then I will gladly help you.

I am setting up the AVCaptureSession and creating an OutputStream using this method. The OutputStream is created by a method in MultipeerConnectivity. More specifically the method: startStream(withName: _, fromPeer: _). If you aren't familiar with this method, it returns the outputStream and sends the inputStream to the peer.

```
func setupAVRecorder() {
do {
    try recordingSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    try recordingSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat)
    try recordingSession.setPreferredSampleRate(44000.00)
    try recordingSession.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(0.2)
    try recordingSession.setActive(true)

    recordingSession.requestRecordPermission() { [unowned self] (allowed: Bool) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if allowed {
                do {
                    self.captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)
                    try self.captureDeviceInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput.init(device: self.captureDevice)

                    self.outputDevice = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
                    self.outputDevice?.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)

                    self.captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
                    self.captureSession.addInput(self.captureDeviceInput)
                    self.captureSession.addOutput(self.outputDevice)
                }
                catch let error {
                    print("\(#file) > \(#function) > ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch let error {
    print("\(#file) > \(#function) > ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------
// Set output stream

if (!outputStreamIsSet) {
    do {
        outputStream = try self.appDelegate.connectionManager.sessions[sessionIndex!].startStream(withName: "audioStream", toPeer: peerID!)
        outputStreamIsSet = true
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("\(#file) > \(#function) > Failed to create outputStream: \(error.localizedDescription)")

        endCallButtonIsClicked(endCallButton) // this just ends the stream
    }
}
}
```

Once the users actually connect to each other, the delegate method gets called. Inside the delegate method we get the InputStream, we open the output and input streams, and finally we start recording using the startRunning() method:

```
func startedStreamWithPeer(_ peerID: MCPeerID, inputStream: InputStream) {
    if (peerID == self.peerID) {

        self.inputStream = inputStream
        self.inputStreamIsSet = true
        self.inputStream?.delegate = self
        self.inputStream?.open()
        self.outputStream?.open()

        self.captureSession.startRunning()
    }
    else {
        print("\(#file) > \(#function) > Should not print.")
    }
}
```

Here is the problem. The captureSession records data to a buffer and calls the captureOutput method (I believe it's a delegate method). Inside of this method I try to convert the CMSampleBuffer to UnsafePointer so that I can write it to the outputStream and it can be received on the other end. The problem, is that I get an error "The operation couldn’t be completed. Bad address". I assume this has something to do with the way I'm recording audio, but I'm not entirely sure.

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    var blockBuffer: CMBlockBuffer?
    var audioBufferList: AudioBufferList = AudioBufferList.init()

    CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(sampleBuffer, nil, &audioBufferList, MemoryLayout<AudioBufferList>.size, nil, nil, kCMSampleBufferFlag_AudioBufferList_Assure16ByteAlignment, &blockBuffer)
    let buffers = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(&audioBufferList)

    for buffer in buffers {
        let output = outputStream?.write((buffer.mData?.load(as: UnsafePointer<UInt8>.self))!, maxLength: Int(buffer.mDataByteSize))

        if (output == -1) {
            let error = outputStream?.streamError
            print("\(#file) > \(#function) > Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

In the last print statement I am getting the error I stated earlier "The operation couldn’t be completed. Bad address".

Does anyone have some expertise in recording audio and then converting that audio into an UnsafePointer object?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
buffer.mData?.load(as: UnsafePointer<UInt8>.self)
```

reads the bytes that `buffer.mData` points to into a `UnsafePointer<UInt8>`
variable, in other words, the pointer is *dereferenced,* and the result
passed as buffer address to the `write()` method.
However, `buffer.mData` points to audio data and not to a (valid)
pointer, and that is why `write()` fails with "Bad address".

What you really want is to "cast" or "reinterpret" `buffer.mData`
as a `UnsafePointer<UInt8>`, and that is done with

```
let u8ptr = buffer.mData!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
let output = outputStream!.write(u8ptr, maxLength: Int(buffer.mDataByteSize))
```

(I leave it to you to replace the forced unwraps with optional bindings
or optional chaining.)

Comment: Thanks you @Martin that fixed the issue. The only problem now is that the InputStream delegate method "func stream(Stream, eventCode)" is not being called... I suppose that's another issue though.